# Why isn't F# Interactive displaying line of code after "send selection to F# Interactive" is clicked?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-mac, f#-interactive

I am new to F# and Visual Studio. I am following the F# tutorial provided by Visual Studio and the project runs fine, but whenever I try to highlight a line of code and perform "Send selection to F# Interactive" the window pulls up but nothing displays. I also do not have the ability to perform any actions in F# Interactive. Some background info:

- I'm using a 2020 MacBook Pro and 2019 Visual Studio
- I had previously installed Rider for class but then my professor switched to Visual Studio, not sure if having both installed causes a conflict?

Below is a video showing the VS tutorial file I'm working in and some of the problems I'm experiencing.

https://youtu.be/2hdBlm-h2i4

I appreciate any help as I have to keep using Visual Studio, F#, and F# Interactive for class and do not want to fall behind, thank you!

Comment: I believe this a bug in Visual Studio for Mac 8.10. Can you try version 8.9 and see if that works for you? Download link - https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/bb523eea-3c8a-4ce8-95ff-5d9c3f157689/3a67b58861b2d0d4f50a16656b8f6e74/visualstudioformac-8.9.10.4.dmg

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!